# Google states my viewport is not set, site not responsive on IOS

Tags: html, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3. In my document I have:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
```

When I use chrome dev tools and shrink the page or choose mobile view it works perfect. On my iphone 6 it is always desktop view.

I ran google mobile friendly test and it returned:

Text too small to read
Links too close together
Mobile viewport not set

Am I missing some other piece of code that is relevant?

Comment: Can you link us to the site, so we can see if it's something else in the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was forwarding with Masking to heroku, and google was not able to read my meta tags.

Comment: Same issue - commercial server. Viewport is present. Why not able to read? http://newmarketnhhistoricalsociety.org/